# Android Exoplayer : What is 'playWhenReady' in "onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState)" method

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, exoplayer

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    switch (playbackState) {
        case Player.STATE_IDLE:  **//1.When this happens ?**

            if (playWhenReady==false) {  **//2.What "playWhenReady" indicate ?**

                **//3.When this condition occur ?**
            }
            else{
                **//4.When this condition occur ?**
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

What is '**playWhenReady**' in "**onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState)**" method ? & When does player goes to '**Player.STATE_IDLE**'? When does all four Stages mention in given code occurs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links answer your questions.

- http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.EventListener.html#onPlayerStateChanged-boolean-int-
- http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#STATE_IDLE

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs

```
void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady,int playbackState)
```

Invoked when the value returned from either ExoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady() or ExoPlayer.getPlaybackState() changes.
    playWhenReady - Whether playback will proceed when ready.
    playbackState - One of the STATE constants defined in the ExoPlayer interface.

[Checkout the link.](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4580)

[Checkout the docs](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.EventListener.html)

Hope this solves the issue.